# Tatpurusha in Gayathri Mantra

Tags: gayatri-mantra, hymn

Gayathri mantra dedicated to several gods contains **Tatpurusha**. For example Shiva Gayathri mantra is

> Om Tatpurushaya vidmahe Mahadevaya Dhimahi
>
> Tanno Rudra prchodayat

and Subrahmanya Gayathri Mantra is

> Om Tatpurushaya vidmahe Mahasenaya Dhimahi
>
> Tanno Shanmuga Prachodayath

Which God does Tatpurusha in the Gaythri Mantras refer to?

Comment: You mean the word should refer to some other deity despite being present in a mantra that is dedicated to a particular deity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tatpurusha is not a God. "Tat" (तत्) literally means "that".

"Purusha" is a concept referring to the Cosmic Self, Cosmic Consciousness, or the Universal Principle. This concept came about from the *[Purusha Suktam](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/invoc/in_pura.html)* when it referred to a cosmic man who was sacrificed by the gods to create all life. In Yoga philosophy, Purusha also references the true Self - the realization of which is a goal of yoga practice as defined in The Yoga Sutras of Patanjali. It is also the ultimate goal of all Vedic practices and Vedantic philosophy, examination and inquiry.

**Shwetashvatara Upanishad Adhyaya III** defines Purusha as such:

> **mahān prabhur vai puruṣaḥ sattvasyaiṣa pravartakaḥ | 
>
>   sunirmalām imāṃ prāptim īśāno jyotir avyayaḥ || (3.12)**
>
> *That person (**purusha**) is the great lord; he is the mover of 
>   existence, he possesses that purest power of reaching everything, he
>   is light, he is undecaying.*
>
> **aṅguṣṭhamātraḥ puruṣo 'ntarātmā sadā janānāṃ hṛdaye saṃniviṣṭaḥ |
>
>   hṛdā manīṣā manasābhikḷpto ya etad vidur amṛtās te bhavanti || (3.13)**
>
> *The person (**purusha**), not larger than a thumb, dwelling within, 
>   always dwelling in the heart of man, is perceived by the heart, the
>   thought, the mind: they who know it become immortal.*
>
> **sahasraśīrṣā puruṣaḥ sahasrākṣaḥ sahasrapāt |
>
>   sa bhūmiṃ viśvato vṛtvā atyatiṣṭhad daśāṅgulam || (3.14)**
>
> *The person (**purusha**) with a thousand heads, a thousand eyes, a 
>   thousand feet, having compassed the earth on every side, extends
>   beyond it by ten fingers’ breadth.*
>
> **puruṣa evedaṃ sarvaṃ yad bhūtaṃ yac ca bhavyam |
>
>   utāmrtatvasyeśāno yad annenātirohati || (3.15)**
>
> *That person alone (**purusha**) is all this, what has been and what 
>   will be; he is also the lord of immortality; he is whatever grows by
>   food.*

Tatpurusha (तत्पुरुष) is also one of the eleven emanations of Rudra, according to the Roopamandana (a text of Shilpa shastra). Other emanations are : Ishana, Aghora, Vamadeva, Sadyojatha, Mrityunjaya, Kiranaksha, Srikanta, Abhirbhudhya, Bahurupa and Tryambaka.

So ultimately, Tatpurusha refers to the cosmic self in all Jivas.

Therefore the Shanmukha (Subhramanya) Gayatri mantra translates to

***"Om, Let me meditate on that (tat) great male (purusha),
Oh, commander in chief, give me higher intellect,
And let the six faced one illuminate my mind."***